# Java 2D and resize

Tags: java, image, resize, 2d, image-scaling

I have some old Java 2D code I want to reuse, but was wondering, is this the best way to get the highest quality images?

```
    public static BufferedImage getScaled(BufferedImage imgSrc, Dimension dim) {

    //  This code ensures that all the pixels in the image are loaded.
    Image scaled = imgSrc.getScaledInstance(
            dim.width, dim.height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

    // This code ensures that all the pixels in the image are loaded.
    Image temp = new ImageIcon(scaled).getImage();

    // Create the buffered image.
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(temp.getWidth(null), 
            temp.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    // Copy image to buffered image.
    Graphics g = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
    // Clear background and paint the image.
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, temp.getWidth(null),temp.getHeight(null));
    g.drawImage(temp, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();


    // j2d's image scaling quality is rather poor, especially when
    // scaling down an image to a much smaller size. We'll post filter  
    // our images using a trick found at 
    // http://blogs.cocoondev.org/mpo/archives/003584.html
    // to increase the perceived quality....
    float origArea = imgSrc.getWidth() * imgSrc.getHeight();
    float newArea = dim.width * dim.height;
    if (newArea <= (origArea / 2.)) {
        bufferedImage = blurImg(bufferedImage);
    }

    return bufferedImage;
}

public static BufferedImage blurImg(BufferedImage src) {
    // soften factor - increase to increase blur strength
    float softenFactor = 0.010f;
    // convolution kernel (blur)
    float[] softenArray = {
            0,              softenFactor,       0, 
            softenFactor, 1-(softenFactor*4), softenFactor, 
            0,              softenFactor,       0};

    Kernel kernel = new Kernel(3, 3, softenArray);
    ConvolveOp cOp = new ConvolveOp(kernel, ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP, null);
    return cOp.filter(src, null);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chris Campbell has an excellent and detailed write-up on scaling images - see **[this article](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html)**.

Chet Haase and Romain Guy also have a detailed and very informative write-up of image scaling in their book, **[Filthy Rich Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org/)**.

Answer (score 3):

Adding some clarifying information here.

No, that isn't the *best* way to get a good looking scaled image in Java. Use of getScaledInstance and the underlying AreaAveragingScaleFilter are deprecated by the Java2D team in favor of some more advanced methods.

If you are just trying to get a good-looking thumbnail, using Chris Campbell's method as suggested by David is the way to go. For what it's worth, I have implemented that algorithm along with 2 other faster methods in a Java image-scaling library called [imgscalr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/) (Apache 2 license). The point of the library was to specifically address this question in a highly tuned library that is easy to use:

```
BufferedImage thumbnail = Scalr.resize(srcImg, 150);
```

To get the best-looking scaled instance possible in Java, the method call would look something like this:

```
BufferedImage scaledImg = Scalr.resize(img, Method.QUALITY, 
                                       150, 100, Scalr.OP_ANTIALIAS);
```

The library will scale the original image using the incremental-scaling approach recommended by the Java2D team and then to make it look even nicer a very mild convolveop is applied to the image, effectively anti-aliasing it slightly. This is really nice for small thumbnails, not so important for huge images.

If you haven't worked with convolveops before, it's a LOT of work just to get the perfect looking kernel for the op to look good in all use-cases. The OP constant defined on the Scalr class is the result of a week of collaboration with a social networking site in Brazil that had rolled out imgscalr to process profile pictures for it's members. We went back and forth and tried something like 10 different kernels until we found one that was subtle enough not to make the image look soft or fuzzy but still smooth out the transitions between pixel values so the image didn't look "sharp" and noisey at small sizes.

If you want the *best looking* scaled image regardless of speed, go with Juha's suggestion of using the java-image-scaling library. It is a very comprehensive collection of Java2D Ops and includes support for the [Lanczsos algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm) which will give you the best-looking result.

I would stay away from JAI, not because it's bad, but because it is just a different/broader tool than what you are trying to solve. Any of the previous 3 approaches mentioned will give you great looking thumbnails without needing to add a whole new imaging platform to your project in fewer lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JAI (Java Advanced Imaging) to get more sophisticated image resizing options.  See https://jai.dev.java.net/.  These allow you much more flexibility than the java.awt.image package.

Answer (score 1):

You could also look into [java-image-scaling](http://code.google.com/p/java-image-scaling/) library.

Answer (score 1):

You can Resize Image using a Open Source Library
[enter link description here](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/)

I have done with Large Image to Small and result excellent, keeping the aspect ratio fine.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import org.imgscalr.*;
import org.imgscalr.Scalr.Method;


public class ImageScaller {
static String SRC_FILES_PATH = "I:\\BigGreen\\";
static String IMAGE_FILE_PATH = "I:\\Resized\\";
public ImageScaller() {         
}   
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try
    {
        ResizeLoad(SRC_FILES_PATH);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
}
public static int ResizeLoad(String path)
{
    String file;
    File folder ;
    File[] listOfFiles = null;       
    listOfFiles = null;
    try
    {           
        folder = new File(path);
        listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();   

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)                    
        {                   
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile())
            {
                file = listOfFiles[i].getName();
                ScalledImageWrite(listOfFiles[i].getPath(),file);                                   
                //System.out.println(file);
                }
            }
        System.out.println("All Resized");
        }

    catch (Exception e) 
      {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.toString(),"Resize & Load :Exception",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);                
      }
    return listOfFiles.length;
}
private static File ScalledImageWrite(String path,String fileName) 
  {
      try
      {
          BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(path));            
          BufferedImage scaledImg = Scalr.resize(img, Method.AUTOMATIC, 24, 24);                 
          File destFile = new File(IMAGE_FILE_PATH + fileName);      
          ImageIO.write(scaledImg, "png", destFile);                  
          //System.out.println("Done resizing");
          return destFile;
      }
      catch (Exception e) 
      {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.toString(),"Scalled Images Write: Exception",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
          return null;
      }
  }

}
```

Here is the output in pictorial format of this code.
[image]